# Overriding in Scala, overloaded Java methods distinguished by array type

Tags: scala

While creating stub implementations of `java.sql.Connection`, `DataSource`, `ResultSet` &c. for a Scala functional test I came across several cases where a Java method is overloaded, with each method distinguished only by the type of an array parameter. For instance (from `java.sql.Connection`):

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql, int[] columnIndexes) throws SQLException
PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames) throws SQLException
```

Converted to Scala, it looks like this:

```
override def prepareStatement(sql: String, columnIndexes: Array[Int]): PreparedStatement 
override def prepareStatement(sql: String, columnNames: Array[String]): PreparedStatement
```

but in Scala 2.9.2, this won't compile as we are distinguishing only by a parametric type. Other than implementing the stubs in Java, can anyone propose a clever solution?

I was surprised not to be able to find any prior discussion of this particular Scala/Java interop issue ... it's easy enough to find discussion of the similar issue with varargs. Surely someone has run into this issue before? Any pointers to earlier discussion or issues in the Scala issue tracker?

Comment: this is really interesting. It seems like array generalization in Scala loses specificity in the process, as the nine kinds of arrays in Java are actually nine unrelated distinct types.

Comment: Er ... did you try compiling it? The following looks well enough for me:
`object Foo { def bar(a: Array[Int]) = 1; def bar(a: Array[String]) = 2 }` and then `Foo.bar(Array(1))` returns 1 and `Foo.bar(Array("hello"))` returns 2. This is Scala 2.10.0.

Comment: What Scala version are you using and what compiler error are you getting. I was able to implement `Connection` just fine in a REPL session.

Comment: I can confirm I'm able to overload based on Array type in scala 2.11 too

Comment: Defining the two overloads above also works fine in 2.9.2 (and previous versions), so does @GabrielePetronella's REPL transcript. Can you share the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 7):

It's an interesting issue, but it looks like in modern versions of the compiler this has been fixed.

In scala 2.11.2

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def prepareStatement(sql: String, columnNames: Array[String]): String = "foo"
def prepareStatement(sql: String, columnIndexes: Array[Int]): String = "bar"

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

prepareStatement: (sql: String, columnNames: Array[String])String <and> (sql: String, columnIndexes: Array[Int])String
prepareStatement: (sql: String, columnNames: Array[String])String <and> (sql: String, columnIndexes: Array[Int])String

scala> prepareStatement("bah", Array(1,2,3))
res11: String = bar

scala> prepareStatement("bah", Array("foo","bar","baz"))
res12: String = foo
```

and - based on @sjrd's comment - the same works in scala 2.10.0 too.

What version did you test it on?

Comment: Ah now that is interesting. I'm on scala 2.9.2